# Integer comparison in MySQL query not working correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

i've been having an issue comparing two integers in a `MySQL` query, it is not finding any results but should be. the query I am using :

```
"SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE var1 = '" . $variable1 . "' 
AND var2 = '" . $variable2 . "' 
AND var3 = 3"
```

if I leave out the `AND var3 = 3` bit, it works fine, however with it in, it won't return any results.

In the database, `var3` is stored as a `tinyint`, and has a value of 3 for every user at the moment for testing purposes. Is there something I am missing here? any help is greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: nothing wrong with the query or having a tinyint - you probably just don't have the records you think you do.

Comment: @Mark B I thought this at first, but looking in the database the results are there, and also I took out the var3=3 part, and ran an echo var3; and it gave me 3. I'm really confused!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using PDO or mysqli so that you can bind parameters and avoid injection.  It also makes it easier to read, in my opinion.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users 
       WHERE var1 = ? 
       AND var2 = ?
       AND var3 = 3';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($variable1, $variable2));
```

<strike>This also avoids mistakes like adding single quotes to the integer values, which you did in yours.</strike>

Comment: I appreciate the advice I will look into this, I have looked into mysqli and PDO but my currently provider supports neither at the moment, I may look into changing my provider for this to be honest. However the single quotes where not a mistake, the first two variables are strings not integers.

Comment: After reading through your other comments, I realize I assumed $variable1 and $variable2 were integers for some reason.  If my code above doesn't work, you should execute your query in a SQL client or phpmyadmin to make sure it's not a problem with your query or table.

For instance, try "SELECT var3 FROM users" to make sure your var3 column is stored correctly.  Then try "SELECT * FROM users WHERE var3 = 3" if that works.

Comment: @user1959287 are you sure you don't have PDO?  It has come with every PHP since 5.1.

Comment: I think I have actually just figured out the issue thanks to this. var3 is something i substituted for safety reasons, the actual variable is called 'group', i wasn't aware there was a mysql GROUP also. Is there any way to escape this issue or does it simply mean changing the variable name?

Comment: @ChrisMoll I will double check, it was a while ago I checked and my provider hasn't been the most 'efficient' at updating their PHP version!

Comment: Excellent! That was the issue, the name in the database was 'group' and so when searching for AND group = 3, it was classing it as AND GROUP = 3 causing a mysql error, all working now, help is much appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

its about your var1 and var2 if they string or int

in your php file try to let `$variable1` and `$variable1` like `integers`

like that

```
          $variable1 = INTVAL($variable1) ;
          $variable2 = INTVAL($variable2) ;
```

and in your query do like that

```
   "SELECT * FROM users 
   WHERE var1 = $variable1
     AND var2 = $variable2 
   AND var3 = 3"
```

and then it will work in your sql

Comment: Both variable1 and variable2 are string values being compared to string values, these work fine without the var3 part, its only when var3 is added it refuses to throw out any values :S

Comment: it doesnt work as i answered ?